# Codeigniter retchet websocket chat application is not working on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpwebsocket

I have developed a `CodeIgniter` based chat application and I am using `WebSocket` in this application. This code is working fine in the local `xampp` server but when this code is going into live server then this error is occurring

> "WebSocket connection to 'ws://204.11.59.91:8282/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Comment: have you run WebSocket server on production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Look for open the port 8282, you IP is ok with ping, but the port not available with telnet